# Bootstrap nav bar collapses but is not clickable on mobile

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

My navbar is able to collapse on moblile but nothing happens when I click the collapsed button. The nav bar works perfectly on desktop. But when I get on mobile I see the collapsed three lines but nothing happens when I click them. Anyone know how to get out of this one?

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SQUR</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds">Spaces</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds/new">New Space</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form action="/campgrounds/find" class="d-flex" href="/campgrounds/find" method="GET">
                <input class="form-control me-2 mr-1" type="text" placeholder="Search a city" aria-label="Search"
                    name="city" id="city">

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input  mt-2" type="checkbox" id="agent" value="agent" name="agent"
                        id="agent">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-light" for="anegt">Agents</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input mt-2" type="checkbox" id="spaces" name="spaces" id="spaces"
                        value="spaces">
                    <label class="form-check-label text-light" for="spaces">Spaces</label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success ml-2 mr-3">Search</button>
            </form>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <% if(!currentUser) {%>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
                    <% } else {%>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                        <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

load properly bootstrap js file, I think it will solve  your problem

Answer (score 0):

Put Bootstrap script before the closing body tag.

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```